# QGIS extracted azimuth used for symbol rotation seems not reproduced faithfully

Tags: point, qgis-3, svg, rotate

A field of calculated azimuths* (degrees) of digitized two-point lines was created. Field expression to calculate azimuth:

```
degrees( azimuth( point_n( $geometry ,1) , point_n( $geometry ,2 ) ) ) .
```

Using **Vector Geometry / Extract Specific Vertices** using node 1, a point layer was created from the line layer. The point layer included the azimuth field and the process created an angle field with identical values as the calculated azimuths. For the point layer, a linear-based svg symbol using a data-defined override of the azimuth for rotation (degrees required), symbols appear close to original only when near azimuths of 90 and 180 degrees but are off by what appears to be up to 15 or 20 degrees at intermediate rotations. Has anyone encountered and resolved this?

Comment: What CRS are you using for the project and for the layers?

Comment: That solved my problem. New layers I made were not in project crs, newbie goof on my part.